# how to accept values from the user within a loop in php and store it in an array..i tied the following code..its not working

Tags: php

```
         $prob=array(10);
        echo "enter the probabilites:";
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
        {

              echo"<script language='javascript'>$prob[$i]=prompt('Enter the values');</script>";
        }
```

how to accept values from the user within a loop in php and store it in an array..i tied the following code..its not working 
please help!! i want to store values to the array prob.. i want the users to enter the values.i tried use prompt but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not clear on what is being done on the server and what is being done on the client.  I think your want your page to have a form where the data will be entered; then the form data will be submitted to a (could be the same) server php routine.